# Constraining Field of view in visual servoing

Tags: visual-servoing

I am using image based visual servoing using an eye-in-hand camera. However the camera's motion sometimes servos such that the image features are out of the field of view,and servoing stops. Is there any way to constrain the camera motion such that the image features always remain within the camera field of view ?